# How to send data and get headers on client side e.g. index.html from node server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, token, server-side-rendering, request-headers

I want to send data from node server to statically rendered index.html

I have tried setting cookies by res.cookies but not able to access those cookies on client side

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [EJS](https://ejs.co/) to achieve this

EJS is a template system. You define HTML pages in the EJS syntax and you specify where various data will go in the page. Then, your app combines data with the template and "renders" a complete HTML page where EJS takes your data and inserts it into the web page according to how you've defined the template. For example, you could have a table of dynamic data from a database and you want EJS to generate the table of data according to your display rules. It saves you from the drudgery of writing code to dynamically generate HTML based on data.